# Intersection of a dense set with an open set is dense in the open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A\subset M$ an open subset of the metric space M. If $X\subset M$ is dense in M, then $X\cap A$ is dense in A.

My approach:

If $X\subset M$ is a dense subset of $M$, and $A\subset M$ is an open subset. Let be $U (\neq \phi) \subset A$ be an open set in $A$. Then U is an open subset in M. Therefore $U\cap X\neq \emptyset$. And now, $U\cap X=(U\cap A)\cap X = U\cap(A\cap X)$, and then $A\cap X$ is dense. But I am not sure if this is okay. Any help. Regards

Comment: Seems fine to me!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't sure of $U\cap X\neq \emptyset$, this is my problem. regards

Comment: This is a theorem. 
 $X$ dense in $M \iff \big(\forall U \in (\mathcal{T}(d)-\{\emptyset\}): U\cap X \neq \emptyset\big)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is basically correct. Here is a more careful and mostly equivalent argument.

To show $X \cap A$ is dense in $A$, we need to show that every nonempty open set in $A$ intersects $X \cap A$.
So take $U \subset A$ open in $A$, and nonempty.
Note that **$\boldsymbol{U}$ is open in $\boldsymbol{A}$ iff it is open in $\boldsymbol{M}$**, so $U$ is open in $M$.
Therefore $U \cap X \neq \varnothing$, and therefore $U \cap (A \cap X) = U \cap X \neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following lemma

> If $A\subset M$ is open, then $A\cap\overline{X}\subset\overline{A\cap X}$ for every $X\subset M$.

Then if $A\subset M$ is open and $X\subset M$ is dense in $M$ then $$\overline{A\cap X}\supset A\cap\overline{X}=A\cap M=A$$

which implies that $A=\overline{A\cap X}$, that is, $A\cap X$ is dense in $A$.